# Trying to make a pie menu with custom operator

Tags: scripting, operator

Trying to understand how i can add the operator i made to a pie menu for me to use, when i run it nothing shows. Treat me like a noob at coding, thank you for your time

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator

# spawn an edit mode selection pie (run while object is in edit mode to get a valid output)

class hyperbevel(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'Hyper.Bevel'
    bl_label = 'HyperBevel'

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False,use_expand=False, type='EDGE')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.mark_sharp(clear=True)
        bpy.ops.transform.edge_bevelweight(value=-1)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
        bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_remove(modifier="Bevel")
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].limit_method = 'WEIGHT'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].segments = 3
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.edges_select_sharp()
        bpy.ops.mesh.mark_sharp()
        bpy.ops.transform.edge_bevelweight(value=1)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.context.object.data.use_auto_smooth = True
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].width = 0.02
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].use_clamp_overlap = False
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier="Bevel")
        return ('finished')



class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Operators"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # operator_enum will just spread all available options
        # for the type enum of the operator on the pie
        pie.operator("Hyper.Bevel", text = "Hyperbevel")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_PIE_template")
```

Comment: Copy the code and paste it in question via code

Comment: sorry first time posting a code, is it like this?

Comment: there is a button **code** in text editor

Comment: ya i think i got it, not sure if people can see though

Comment: now people can copy the code and test it

Comment: another way is via blender txt editor, ctrl-A tab ctrl-C shift-tab, respectively selects all, tabs all one tab right  (the code markdown required for bse), copy, and shift-tab tabs it back one left.  Paste into bse and will be formatted correctly.  IMO easier than paste in bse, select the newly pasted and code button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Register the operator class**

- Register the operator class.  The `bl_idname` needs to be in all
  lower case, with one period. Blender 2.8 is a lot stricter on this
  and must follow the naming convention between class and operator eg
  `OBJECT_OT_MyOperator` and `object.myoperator`  [Links]
- The operator returns a `set` that contains one of `('RUNNING_MODAL',
  'CANCELLED', 'FINISHED', 'PASS_THROUGH', 'INTERFACE')`  in this case
  `{'FINISHED'}` which is a set as indicated by the curly braces.

Amended code.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator

# spawn an edit mode selection pie (run while object is in edit mode to get a valid output)

class HyperBevel(Operator):
    bl_idname = "hyper.bevel"
    bl_label = "HyperBevel"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        --- removed for brevity ---
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_move_up(modifier="Bevel")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Operators"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator("hyper.bevel")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)
    bpy.utils.register_class(HyperBevel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HyperBevel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_PIE_template")
```

Comment: thank you so much, ya sorry i didnt know much thank you again for taking your time